# In wxpython copy, cut, paste, and select all text from one TextCtrl to an other

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to cut, paste, copy, and select the text from textcrtl to textcrtl. Can anyone help me please, my mind has stack for hours. Look the code below, thanks for your help...

```
import wx
import os

class Editor(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 500))

        # setting up menubar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        edit = wx.Menu()
        cut = wx.MenuItem(edit, 106, '&Cut\tCtrl+X', 'Cut the Selection')
        edit.AppendItem(cut)

        copy = wx.MenuItem(edit, 107, '&Copy\tCtrl+C', 'Copy the Selection')
        edit.AppendItem(copy)

        paste = wx.MenuItem(edit, 108, '&Paste\tCtrl+V', 'Paste text from clipboard')
        edit.AppendItem(paste)

        delete = wx.MenuItem(edit, 109, '&Delete', 'Delete the selected text')
        edit.AppendItem(delete)

        edit.Append(110, 'Select &All\tCtrl+A', 'Select the entire text')

        menubar.Append(edit, '&Edit')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCut, id=106)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnCopy, id=107)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPaste, id=108)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDelete, id=109)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSelectAll, id=110)

        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', (110,55),(120, -1))
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', (110,95),(120, -1))
        self.text.SetFocus()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnCut(self, event):
         self.text.Cut()

    def OnCopy(self, event):
         self.text.Copy()

    def OnPaste(self, event):
        self.text.Paste()

    def OnDelete(self, event):
        frm, to = self.text.GetSelection()
        self.text.Remove(frm, to)

    def OnSelectAll(self, event):
       self.text.SelectAll()


app = wx.App()
Editor(None, -1, 'Editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Why do you initialize the TextCtrl twice?

Comment: Its a different TextCtrl,see the position of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the `wx.TextCtrl` instance from which to cut, copy or where to paste text. In the code snippet you provided, you tried to do it with `self.text`, but as Velociraptors has already said, you initialized `self.text` twice, so you lost the access to the first `wx.TextCtrl` by name. Therefore, first you have to get `wx.TextCtrl` instance you are working with, and then use its methods. This could be done with `wx.Frame.FindFocus()` class, which returns the widget in a frame which has the focus (or `None`).

So, for `Cut` we get something like this:

```
def OnCut(self, event):
    text = self.FindFocus()
    if text is not None:
        text.Cut()
```

Other methods can be modified the same way.